# Conversion from Timestamp in Java to HSQLDB Interval

Tags: timestamp, hsqldb, spring-jdbc

I am using Spring/JDBC to try to insert a Timestamp object from java into HSQLDB.
I have one column in the table with sql type **INTERVAL MINUTE(4) TO SECOND(6)**.

How would I insert the timestamp into the HSQLDB with a column marked as an interval?
As a fact, I know difference between two timestamps yields an interval type, but I am not sure if I need to convert this before making the query to the db.

Below is the code I have so far.

```
jdbcTemplate.update(SQLConstants.INSERT_OBJECT_SQL,
            new Object[] { obj.getTimestamp()},
            new int[] { Types.TIMESTAMP });
```

And my sql query is

```
INSERT INTO sample_table (timeinterval) VALUES (CAST (? AS INTERVAL MINUTE(4) TO SECOND(6)))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your column definition allows storing values smaller than 10000 minutes. A TIMESTAMP cannot be cast into an INTERVAL. Your query must compute the difference between two TIMESTAMP values and the values must be very close otherwise the difference overflows the INTERVAL field.

An example is below

```
INSERT INTO sample_table(timeinterval) VALUES 
   (CURRENT_TIMESTAMP - CAST (? AS TIMESTAMP)) MINUTE(4) TO SECOND(6)
```